# In SQL using the COUNT function with 1 column needing 2 answers

Tags: mysql

SQL CH4 the question is: "How many trips are in the states of Maine(ME) or Massachusetts (MA)?"

I tried:

```
SELECT STATE, COUNT(*)
FROM TRIP
GROUP BY STATE IN ('MA','ME');
```

The Outcome gave me:

```
STATE (NH) 25, (ME) 16.
```

I can't figure out how to get Maine and Massachusetts in the same answer.

Comment: Is there any reason to capitalize question?

Comment: please ask a clear question, show us the table on which you are running the query

Comment: can you clarify your question little bit..i am still reading it..what is trips?

Comment: I know that sql queries are usually capitalized but the rest of your question must shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want (although you have not asked a **clear** question)-
`SELECT COUNT(STATE) FROM TRIP WHERE STATE IN ('MA','ME');`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try this
`SELECT state, COUNT(id) FROM items_by_state 
GROUP BY state HAVING state IN ('MA','ME');`

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. This is the first time I've asked a question.

Comment: mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM TRIP;
+---------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+----------+--------------+----------+--------------+
| TRIP_ID | TRIP_NAME                        | START_LOCATION      | STATE | DISTANCE | MAX_GRP_SIZE | TYPE     | SEASON       |
+---------+----------------------------------+---------------------+-------+----------+--------------+----------+--------------+
|